# How can we find out if an email address really exists or not?

Tags: asp.net

We can validate an email address with a regular expression in asp.net. Now, **how can we find that an email address really exists or not?**

For example, `farzaneh@yahoo.com` has correct email format but does not exist.

This code work on gmail account only:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
       string CRLF = "\r\n";
       byte[] dataBuffer;
       string ResponseString;
       NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
       /* Perform HELLO to SMTP Server and get Response */
       dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO " + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
       dataBuffer = BytesFromString("MAIL FROM:<hosseinhagh66@gmail.com>" + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
       /* Read Response of the RCPT TO Message to know from google if it exist or not */
       dataBuffer = BytesFromString("RCPT TO:<" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + ">" + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

       if (GetResponseCode(ResponseString) == 550)
       {
           Response.Write("Mai Address Does not Exist !");
           Response.Write("<B><font color='red'>Original Error from Smtp Server :</font></b>" + ResponseString);
       }

       /* QUITE CONNECTION */
       dataBuffer = BytesFromString("QUITE" + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       tClient.Close();
   }

   private byte[] BytesFromString(string str)
   {
       return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
   }

   private int GetResponseCode(string ResponseString)
   {
       return int.Parse(ResponseString.Substring(0, 3));
   }
```

Is there any way to know that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: **you can not verify the existence of an email address** without assistance from the user whose address is being verified.

The de facto standard for accomplishing this is **sending a validation email**, which contains a generated one-time-only link for the user to follow to confirm that an email dispatched to that address is getting received.